# Image button onclick event not fire in asp panel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I wonder why my image button onclick and onclient click event in asp panel is not fire..hope help..thanks much.

**Front end code**

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" CssClass="modalPopup panel" style="display:none;" runat ="server" Width = "510px" Height ="450px" >
    <table class="popuptitle round" style="width:100%; margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;" > 
        <tr> <td style="width:90%;" >
        Select Users
        </td> <td style="text-align:right; "><asp:ImageButton ID="btnPopupX" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cross.png" CausesValidation="false" AlternateText="Close" OnClick="btnPopupX_Click" /> </td></tr>
    </table>
```

**Onclick event**

```
  protected void btnPopupX_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (((ImageButton)sender).ID)
            {
                case "btnPopupX":
                    txtSearch.Text = "";
                    loadGrid2();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is `mpop1` on the element? Did you mean `$find("pnlPopup")`?

Comment: thanks for reply...yes ajax:ModalPopupExtender Id is mpop1 @JamesWilkins

Comment: Try this: `OnClientClick="hidePopup()"`

Answer (score 0):

It may not be working because you are not actually calling the JavaScript function.  Try `OnClientClick="hidePopup()"` (with brackets).

More info: https://goo.gl/g9D8Rp

Note: OP edited answer and removed the code mentioned above (which was still in error at the time of this post).

Answer (score 0):

call OnClientClick="hidePopup()" on front end or register this function in code behind file 
btnPopupX.attribute("onclick","hidePopup()");